# ASP.Net Core 2.0 Webapi set log4net

Tags: log4net, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new to asp.net core 2.0. I creating a webapi and want to configure log4net as my logging provider.

I couldn't find some working example in net. Can anyone help me provide the right link or some sample code about how to properly setup log4net in asp.net core 2.0

Things i have done so far is as below and i am not sure how to proceed further.

installed log4net.Extensions.AspNetCore;

### Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();

    // Enable CORS 
    app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials());

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: try the following  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x#third-party-logging-providers

Comment: Thanks but I couldn't find log4net provider in the list.

Comment: [How to use Log4Net with ASP.NET Core for logging](https://dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-use-log4net-with-aspnetcore-for-logging/)

Answer (score 15):

1. Install nuget for Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore/)
2. In `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)` call `loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();`
3. Create log4net.config

More info -> https://github.com/huorswords/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore